# Migrating D5 users to D6 using MigrateDestinationUser

Tags: migrations

I'm using the migrate module to migrate users from a Drupal 5 site to a Drupal 6 site.

MigrateDestinationUser assumes that the source passwords will be plaintext which isn't the case in Drupal 5. Is there any way around this assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per http://drupal.org/node/1349758, you need to add a complete function:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('pass', 'source_password');
...
public function complete($account, $row) {
  db_update('users')
    ->fields(array('pass' => $row->source_password))
    ->condition('uid', $account->uid)
    ->execute();
}
```